# Gaussian integral with complex coefficients

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

We are all familiar with the standard generalized Gaussian integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \exp\left(-ax^2+bx\right)=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right) $$
where $a,b\in \mathbb R$. I wonder if there is a general formula for the complex case
$$\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \exp\left(-\alpha x^2+\beta x\right)=(?)$$
for $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb C$. I have seen a less general version where $\alpha$ is complex with non-zero real part and $\beta$ purely imaginary, but I haven't been able to find a formula for the integral above.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I will, but it's pretty common notation to omit the integration bounds when the integral is performed over the entire real line, especially when the context makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I will consider the case in which $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)=0$ as the case with real part bigger than zero is equal to the real case, while $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha) <0$ implies that the integral diverges (see e.g [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_a_complex_argument_of_the_exponent) ).

We can rewrite the integrand as

$$
\exp\left(-i a\left(x-\frac{i\beta}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{i\beta^2}{4a}\right)
$$
So the starting integral becames, with a substitution
$$
I=e^{-\frac{i\beta^2}{4a}}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-ia y^2} dy=2e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha^2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-ia y^2} dy
$$
Suppose $a<0$ and consider the integral
$$
0=\int_C e^{-iaz^2} dz=\int_0^R e^{-ia y^2} dy+\int_S e^{-iaz^2} dz+\int_D e^{-iaz^2} dz
$$
Where $C$ is the path in the picture
[image]
The integral is zero because the function is holomorphic,

Over $D$: $z=r e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$ and so $dz=e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}} dr$

So
$$
\int_D e^{-iaz^2} dz=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_R^0 e^{ar^2}dr
$$

Over $S$:
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty}\left\| \int_S e^{-iaz^2} dz\right\|\le\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \|\exp(-ia(r e^{i\theta})^2) i R e^{i \theta}\|d \theta= \lim_{R \to \infty} R \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \exp(a R^2 \sin(\theta')) d \theta'
$$
As $a<0$ is it possible to show that such limit converges to zero (see e.g [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) )

So in the end
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-ia y^2}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^\infty e^{ar^2} dr=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4|a|}}
$$

If $a>0$ you can repeat the process by taking $C$ the sector in the quadrant $\operatorname{Re}(z)<0$, $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$. You will obtain
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-ia y^2}=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}}
$$
So in definite the integral, for $\alpha=ia$, is
$$
I= \exp\left(-\frac{i\beta^2}{4 a}-i \operatorname{sgn}(a)\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{|a|}}
$$

**EDIT** this is taken by some handwritten notes i have. I found [this](https://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph215/Gaussian.pdf) that is very similar to the source of these notes ( that i was not able to found and prbably was in italian)

**PS** : [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_a_complex_argument_of_the_exponent) wikipedia article that i have quoted overlooks the fact that the square root of a complex number has $2$ values (it talk about it in the linked article about Fresnel integrals), this is the reason for which all the machinery I wrote is necessary.

Comment: So, to be clear: for any $\beta\in \mathbb C$ as long as $\text{Re }\alpha>0$ the two integrals in the question have exactly the same solution?

Comment: @Noobgrammer You can alway rewrite
$$\exp(-\alpha x^2+\beta x)=\exp\left(-\alpha\left(x +\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}\right)^2 +\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)$$ and do a substitution. So $\beta$ does not change the integration at all (except by adding a multiplicative constant)

Comment: @Noobgrammer If you are worried about the fact that $x \to x +\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}$ transform the extremes of integration: the integration will be permormed over a line parallel to the real line. I have also found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_a_complex_argument_of_the_exponent) that can help

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but since your answer doesn't make it fully explicit: we have $$ \int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \exp\left(-\alpha x^2+\beta x\right)=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\exp\left(\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)$$ for any $\alpha=a_1+ia_2$ (with $a_1>0$) and $\beta=b_1+ib_2$. There is no modulus in the multiplying factor, and no additional sign term.

Comment: @Noobgrammer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153583/integral-of-a-complex-gaussian-function) there is an alternative proof. Btw there is no difference between the formula I have given and the one written there. I have simply said which value the square root takes, depending on the sign of $\mathcal{Im}(\alpha)$. You can technically do it for any complex value. (Assuming the integral converges)

Comment: (cont) more explicitely, if $a \in \mathbb{R} 7 \{0\}$ $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{ia}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{|a|}} e^{\pm i \frac{\pi}{4}}$$